# Call method taking timestamp as parameter from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, truffle, timestamp

I have a Truffle instance of the contract and I call the method like this

`contract_instance.test(1);`

Where `test` in a function that takes a `timestamp` as parameter.

This gives me this error message:

```
Http error response: (400) Failed to parse the request body: No case matched:
  At /kind, unexpected string instead of endorsement
  At /kind, unexpected string instead of seed_nonce_revelation
  At /kind, unexpected string instead of double_endorsement_evidence
  At /kind, unexpected string instead of double_baking_evidence
  At /kind, unexpected string instead of activate_account
  At /kind, unexpected string instead of proposals
  At /kind, unexpected string instead of ballot
  At /kind, unexpected string instead of reveal
  At /parameters/value, no case matched:
    Missing object field int
    At /string, no case matched:
      Unexpected number instead of string
      Unexpected number instead of object
    Missing object field bytes
    Unexpected object instead of array
    Missing object field prim
  At /kind, unexpected string instead of origination
  At /kind, unexpected string instead of delegation
```

How do I express a timestamp value in JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason you need to represent the timestamp as a string. So `contract_instance.test("1");` will work.